# Rails display table alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display the entirety of the user table alphabetically, I know this needs to be done in the controller:
The code which I have been using in my controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 @users = User.find(:all)
 @users.sort! { |a,b| a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase }
 ...
end
```

form code :

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>      
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Receiving the error **undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass**

What have I missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an order clause to your query.

```
@users = User.reorder(:name)
```

I am not sure what you are going for but if you have a significant number of users you should probably add a limit or pagination to this.

Comment: That will come later, just wetting my feet with rails for now.
I seem to be missing, I added the line and receive the error
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1):

You have a user without name, that's why you got that error.
You can avoid that error with

```
@users.sort! { |a,b| a.name.try(:downcase) <=> b.name.try(:downcase) }
```

But it is a ugly solution, the correct way is doing that directly on the query

```
User.order("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think this should belongs to model, I believe that will make your controller code more readable.

and having scope will make your conditions chain able, read more about [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

assuming u have rails 3.x

```
#users model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :asc_by_name, lambda {
    {:order => 'name ASC'}
  }
end 

#users controller
@users = User.asc_by_name
```

and in your loop use,

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.try(:name) %></td>      
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution although I receive an error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
but when I do User.order('name').each do ... it works fine... my be something I messed up

Comment: @Devo, sorry had a typo in scope , just check now, Btw you got that error because of `@users` is nil

Answer (score 0):

Your database engine is usually better suited for sorting so I would sort in the query:

```
@user = User.order(:name)
```

will give you all `User` objects sorted by the `name` column. This would also work the same:

```
@user = User.find(:all, order: :name)
```